# How to desctructure an object to this

Tags: javascript

Here's how destructuring works:

```
let o = {a:0, b:1};
let {a, b} = o;
console.log(a,b);
```

How do I assign properties a, b to `this`?

In a situation like this, for example:

```
class myClass {
    constructror(){
        this.a = null;
        this.b = null;
    }
    myMethod(o){
        //destructure o here, so that 'this' was assigned a and b
    }
}
const o = {a:0, b:1};
const myInstance = new myClass();
myInstance.myMethod(o);
```

Comment: @AndrewLi, sorry, added some missing parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let o = {a: 0, b: 1};
Object.assign(this, o);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me, but I was thinking if there was syntax something like `this {a, b} = o;`

Comment: Not really. By deconstructing the object, you're splitting the values into separate variables, which then must each be assigned to `this`.